# Support for values at top of bar charts

Tags: charts, image-charts

I'm currently transitioning our product from Google Image Charts over to the Image Charts service. I would like to display a numerical value at the top of a bar chart using `chd` or chart data string.

Using Google Image Charts, the following request outputs

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=770x385&chco=ee7495&chds=0%2C78&chbh=96%2C0%2C95&chxt=x&chxs=0%2C000000%2C38&chm=N%2C000000%2C0%2C-1%2C35%2C0%2Ce%3A0%3A15&chxl=0%3A%7C3%2F24%7C3%2F31%7C4%2F7%7C4%2F14&chd=t%3A7%2C2%2C0%2C0
```

[image]

Using Image-Charts, the following request outputs

```
https://image-charts.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=770x385&chco=ee7495&chds=0%2C78&chbh=96%2C0%2C95&chxt=x&chxs=0%2C000000%2C38&chm=N%2C000000%2C0%2C-1%2C35%2C0%2Ce%3A0%3A15&chxl=0%3A%7C3%2F24%7C3%2F31%7C4%2F7%7C4%2F14&chd=t%3A7%2C2%2C0%2C0
```

[image]

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: [Image-Charts](https://www.image-charts.com/) founder here.*

We currently do not have support for `chm=N`, however you can use `chl=` to mimic such feature ([check out our  label documentation](https://documentation.image-charts.com/reference/chart-label/)).

```
&chl=7|2|0|0
```

```
https://image-charts.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=770x385&chco=ee7495&chds=0%2C78&chbh=96%2C0%2C95&chxt=x&chxs=0%2C000000%2C38&chm=N%2C000000%2C0%2C-1%2C35%2C0%2Ce%3A0%3A15&chxl=0%3A%7C3%2F24%7C3%2F31%7C4%2F7%7C4%2F14&chd=t%3A7%2C2%2C0%2C0&chl=7|2|0|0
```

[image]

PS: If you wish to help us priorize our roadmap, please [take a subscription](https://www.image-charts.com) and ask for the support of chm=N

Comment: I have subscribed to the changelog, but I don't see an area to submit this request. Should I request this via Image-Charts' support email?

Comment: Through our email support indeed :)